# Forcefully exit the program from a thread

Tags: haskell

I use the `error` function to communicate a massive programmer mistake (kind of like a c assert), where I want the program to immediately fail and force me to fix an obvious bug (as opposed to standard runtime exceptions).  This has worked well for years, but I'm currently working on a multi-threaded program, where it is now failing me.

Calling `error` in a thread doesn't exit the program.  This is well documented, https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html.  This problem also exists for `System.Exit.die`, `Control.Exception.Base.assert`, etc.

I've seen examples that get around this program by building a heavyweight communication method between sub-threads and the main one, but this is rarely practical for my purposes, for many reasons:

1. My threads are often created by libraries, like conduits mergeSources.
2. `error` is often thrown in library calls, like when you call `head []`.
3. If I need to route through inter-thread communication, it will make it too easy to miss that mechanism.

Is there a way to force the whole program to deliberately crash from a thread?

Comment: If you are doing the `fork`ing yourself, you can catch the `ErrorCall` exception and rethrow it to the main thread. From the docs: "In a standalone GHC program, only the main thread is required to terminate in order for the process to terminate." If the `fork`ing is done by some library function like `mergeSources`, the situation is more complicated - you have less control over which thread the `ErrorCall` is raised in. Do you have an example program? I believe in the case of conduit, you could write a function which wraps each value produced in an exception handler.

Answer (score 2):

The following example works for me on Windows; I import and call the foreign C function `exit`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Main where

import Control.Concurrent

foreign import ccall "exit" exit :: IO ()

main = do
    forkIO exit
    threadDelay 1000000
    putStrLn "Main is still running..."
```